# Can't upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 - dependency issue

Tags: 14.04, 16.04

When I try to upgrade I receive this message:

```
"Required depends is not installed. The required dependency 'apt(>=1.0.1ubuntu2.13) is not installed"
```

Can someone explain what this means.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apt is one of the package management engines in Ubuntu. When you run the upgrade, versus just overwriting everything with a clean install, it downloads and unpacks the new packages over the old ones.

This warning appeared because either apt's integrity (checksum and signature) couldn't be verified or you are using an older version (the most recent one for 14.04 is 1.0.1ubuntu2.15, 16.04 uses 1.2.15).

Check which version you are using by typing

```
sudo dpkg -l apt
```

Into the terminal. If you are using an version lower than the one listed in your error message, you will need to run a full upgrade by running

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```